# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.2

Tags: android, build.gradle

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.2

Shows in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.

It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: app

Comment: please add your app module `build.gradle`  file

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.2

It's because there is no support library `23.0.2`. There is only `23.0.1` in `23.0` minor tree, see https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive#rev23-0-1

You should use the latest version i.e `28.0.0` or migrate your project to use **AndroidX**. See [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.

You need to use implementation or o api for your dependencies block. Something like this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```